# Pandas - GroupBy 2 Columns - Unable to reset index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DF as follows:

```
Date Bought | Fruit
2018-01       Apple
2018-02       Orange
2018-02       Orange
2018-02       Lemon
```

I wish to group the data by 'Date Bought' & 'Fruit' and count the occurrences.

**Expected result:**

```
Date Bought | Fruit | Count
2018-01       Apple     1
2018-02       Orange    2
2018-02       Lemon     1
```

**What I get:**

```
Date Bought | Fruit | Count
2018-01       Apple     1
2018-02       Orange    2
              Lemon     1
```

**Code used:**

```
Initial attempt:
df.groupby(['Date Bought','Fruit'])['Fruit'].agg('count')

#2
df.groupby(['Date Bought','Fruit'])['Fruit'].agg('count').reset_index()
ERROR: Cannot insert Fruit, already exists

#3
df.groupby(['Date Bought','Fruit'])['Fruit'].agg('count').reset_index(inplace=True)
ERROR: Type Error: Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame
```

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) shows that the groupby function returns a 'groupby object' not a standard DF. How can I group the data as mentioned above and retain the DF format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that by resetting the index you'd end up with 2 columns with the same name. Because working with `Series` is possible set parameter `name` in [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['Date Bought','Fruit'], sort=False)['Fruit']
         .agg('count')
         .reset_index(name='Count'))
print (df1)
  Date Bought   Fruit  Count
0     2018-01   Apple      1
1     2018-02  Orange      2
2     2018-02   Lemon      1
```

Comment: Although this is basically a `transform`, as the other answer points out

Comment: @yatu - Are you sure?  I think not.

Comment: Well you lose the index though. You'd have to assign back.